# Partially overlapped Screens in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

How to implement partially overlapped screens in android.
Please find below image.

[image]

It has 3 screens partially overlapped with other.
Suggest possible way to achieve this UI in android.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Use Relative layout and to place them on each other try using negative margins in between components.